# Calculate the number of Tweets in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I want to calculate the number of Tweets of a Twitter Search, and a countup. Just like GigaTweet. How can I calculate this using PHP and the Twitter API?

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of documents and PHP libraries out there to assist you with this:

- http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Libraries#PHP
- http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation

As for the specific method I would use:

- http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method:-search

Example:

- http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=twitter

I would then use simplexml (http://www.php.net/simplexml) to parse the atom feed. From there I would use the [count](https://www.php.net/count) method to get the number of "entry" items in that feed.

Please keep in mind that the atom format uses xml namespaces and you'll have to use the [children](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method to retrieve items correctly. More on this can be found here: http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/10/20/simplexml-and-namespaces/

Comment: @Francesc, if you found my answer helpful could you mark it as accepted? It's been two years.